# Uniqueness validation on nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the current code I have:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent

  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => { :scope => :parent_id, :case_sensitive => false }
end
```

My problem is that when I do:

```
Parent.create(params)
```

The uniqueness validation only checks before any child is created. It never checks again after each child being added. Is there a way to call validations between each child being added?

If there's no ActiveRecord way to do this, I will write my own validation method on parent. But I'm wondering if there's an "easier" way.

This is the logs:

```
Child Exists (0.4ms)
Child Exists (0.2ms)  
Parent Exists (0.3ms) 
SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "parents" 
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "children" 
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "children"
```

Comment: Actually, it performs validation before creation of each `Child` instance. Say, if you already have Child with name "foo" saved in DB, you'll have no chance to save another record with the same name (scoped to `parent_id`). And it is good practice to add uniq index on DB level.

Comment: I've actually tried this and I updated the OP to show the logs.
I removed all the extra stuff but you can see that the validation checks all at once before any child is added. So if you create two children at the same time, it gets through validations. And Yes I can add a uniq index on the DB level but I want a consistent error message.

Answer (score 1):

you jsut try this. something look like

```
# app/validators/products_name_uniqueness_validator.rb
class ProductsNameUniquenessValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors[attribute] << "Products names must be unique" unless value.map(&:name).uniq.size == value.size
  end
end

# app/models/shop.rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :products, :products_name_uniqueness => true
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating another file? Can I add that method to the Shop class?